# Displaying XMLAttribute Values via PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an XML as follows

```xml
<start>
<start.1 StartType="Name1">Value1<start1>
<start.1 StartType="Name1">Value2<start1>
<start.1 StartType="Name1">Value3<start1>
<start.1 StartType="Name1">Value4<start1>
</start>
```

In PowerShell, when I use the following

```bsh
[xml]$xmlFile = Get-Content \path\of\the.xml
$xmlFile.SelectNodes("//start/start1")
```

It displays the following output:

```
StartType                            #text
---------                            ------
Name1                                Value1
Name1                                Value2
Name1                                Value3
Name1                                Value4
```

I would just want to store the Values (Value1, Value2, Value3, value4) in a variable.

For example:

```bsh
$values = $xmlFile.SelectNodes("//start/start1") | Out-String
Write-Host $values
```

The result should be as follows:

```
Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4
```

Comment: I run the following also in powershell
$xml.start.'start.1'

It yield no results

Comment: <start>
<start.1>
< start2 StartType="Name1">Value1</start2>
<start1>
<start.1>
< start2 StartType="Name1">Value1</start2>
<start1>
<start.1>
< start2 StartType="Name1">Value1</start2>
<start1>
<start.1>
< start2 StartType="Name1">Value1</start2>
<start1>
<start.1>
< start2 StartType="Name1">Value1</start2>
<start1>
</start>

Comment: Don't post such lengthy code in comments but rather correct your question. With the example output you provided you could use `Select` to get the values and probably could use something like a `%` or maybe even join to get it as a singular string.

Comment: @Learner That's not valid xml. Opening and closing nodes need to match

Comment: `$xmlFile.SelectNodes("//start/start1") | Out-String` -> `$xmlFile.SelectNodes("//start/start1").'#text' | Out-String`

Comment: If you want to have just the text "Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4" it works: $xmlFile.SelectNodes("//start/start1") -join ', '.